# Mysql select from a table multiple ids and insert them into another table

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have a mysql table called

```
jos_users_quizzes with the following columns:

id
quiz_i
duser_id

I have a second table called  jos_users with this columns
id
name
username
department
```

the user_id on first table is linked with the id of second table so quiz_id = id (jos_users)
How can build a query to multiple insert the ids of a selected department into the jos_users_quizzes table... IN ONE CLICK

I am thinking a sub query or a loop will do , but no sure how to contruct the query.
 I need to select all user ids from selected department. For example have a list of departments, and once the department is selected , select all ids pertaining that department and insert all the Ids into the other table (quizid , (alldepartment ids)

Thanks in advance!

Code from and ASP.NET form to insert ....

```
  string quizidselected = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
            string deptselected = ListBox2.SelectedValue;
            //OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO jos_jquarks_users_quizzes  (quiz_id,user_id) VALUES (' " + quizidselected + " ',677)");
            OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO jos_jquarks_users_quizzes (user_id, quiz_id)    SELECT id, ' " + quizidselected + " ' FROM jos_users  WHERE department = ' " + deptselected + " '");
```

Comment: A little confused here... Are the department ids the id field on jos_users or the department field?\

Comment: yes , well each id on jos_users have a department, so I want t select all ids where department is 'department' selected on a list

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. I get that `jos_users_quizzes.id` links to `jos_users.id`, but you also state *quiz_id = id (jos_users)*, which makes little sense.

Comment: sorry only user_id jos_users_quizzes is equal to id on jos_users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my interpretation of what you want...

```
INSERT INTO jos_users_quizzes (user_id, quiz_id)
    SELECT id, :new_quiz_id
        FROM jos_users
        WHERE department = :department
```

Comment: will this make several insertions, say 20 ids are equal to a selected departemnt?

Comment: Assuming that the 'id' field in 'jos_users_quizzes' is an auto increment field, and assuming that the selected department has 20 users, then yes.

Comment: what are the values after the colon  ? is that mysql syntax?\

Comment: Those are placeholders for variables that I'm assuming you'd be supplying in your application.

Comment: ok query seems to be ok, but the department columnd only exists on the jos_users table, and I get  error

Answer (score 0):

If you set the id using auto increment, then you can do something like this

```
insert into jos_users_quizzes (quiz_i) select id from jos_users;
```

Comment: will this make several insertions, say 20 ids are equal to a selected departemnt?

Comment: Depending on the result, if the `select` operation result contain 20 records then yes.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy if you know keyword like email address, department id or department name.

For example:

```
$depname = "Logistics"; // PHP // department name
$quizid = "Quiz-12"; // PHP // quiz name
```

Then make insert query:

```
<?php 
$query = "INSERT INTO `to_table` (user_id, quiz_id) 
                 SELECT id, '$quizid' FROM `from_table` 
                 WHERE department = '$depname'"; 
?>
```

For more compatibility you can use Lower case if you obtained values from web page, like:

```
<?php 
$query = "INSERT INTO `to_table` (user_id, quiz_id) 
                 SELECT id, LOWER('%$quizid%') 
                 FROM `from_table` 
                 WHERE department like LOWER('%$depname%')"; 
?>
```

Use addslashes command for protecting database when you insert data from web page:

```
<?php 
$query = "INSERT INTO `to_table` (user_id, quiz_id) 
                 SELECT id, LOWER('%".addslashes($quizid)."%') 
                 FROM `from_table` 
                 WHERE department like LOWER('%".addslashes($depname)."%')"; 
?>
```